# Getting Component link field values

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.6

DXA 1.6 / MVC

We are getting NULL from a field that should contain a list of Components (`itemListElement`):

(Note: we are able to see the values of `SectionHeading` and `SubHeading` as expected)

```
[SemanticEntity(Vocab = CoreVocabulary, EntityName = "ImageCardList", Prefix = "s", Public = true)]
public class ImageCardList : EntityModel
{
    [SemanticProperty("s:sectionHeading")]
    public string SectionHeading { get; set; }

    [SemanticProperty("s:subHeading")]
    public string SubHeading { get; set; }

    [SemanticProperty("s:itemListElement")]
    public List<ImageCardItem> ItemListElement { get; set; }
}
```

ImageCardItem:

```
[SemanticEntity(EntityName = "ImageCard", Prefix = "s", Vocab = CoreVocabulary, Public = true)]
public class ImageCardItem: EntityModel
{
    [SemanticProperty("s:headline")]
    public string Headline { get; set; }

    [SemanticProperty("s:content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [SemanticProperty("s:media")]
    public MediaItem Media { get; set; }

    [SemanticProperty("s:link")]
    public Link Link { get; set; }
}
```

All fields in Tridion match up with the SemanticProperties specified above:

[image: 1]

itemListElement only allows an "ImageCard" schema to be used:

[image: 2]

There is no controller, just a view:

```
@using Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html;
@model ImageCardList

@if (Model.ItemListElement != null)
{
    // HTML HERE
}
```

Finding it difficult to find any information on this - I imagine it is possible as we have previously done this using RazorTemplating.

Any help would be most appreciated - happy to give more information!

EDIT: Logs below:

```
2017-06-07 08:56:14,253 [11] TRACE -     HtmlHelperExtensions.DxaEntities(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper`1[Sdl.Web.Common.Models.RegionModel], 0) entry.
2017-06-07 08:56:14,253 [11] TRACE -       HtmlHelperExtensions.DxaEntity(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper`1[Sdl.Web.Common.Models.RegionModel], ImageCardList: 333, 12) : BLAH:Entity:ImageCardCarousel entry.
2017-06-07 08:56:14,254 [11] TRACE -       HtmlHelperExtensions.DxaEntity() exit. Duration: 0 ms.
2017-06-07 08:56:14,254 [11] TRACE -     HtmlHelperExtensions.DxaEntities() exit. Duration: 1 ms.
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and supply some details about the Schema `ImageCardList`, specifically the XML names of its fields

Comment: Added extra details on the schema "ImageCardList"

Comment: Which version of DXA are you using? Note that DXA 1.7 has improved diagnostic logging (set log level to DEBUG) for model mapping issues.

Comment: We are using DXA 1.6 - nothing in the logs suggest there is anything wrong.

Comment: Is it a new field you recently added? Did you republish the system "Settings" page?

Comment: @HaoPeng Everything is new :) All other field types appear to work (Text/image etc)

Comment: Maybe double check the RootElement of ImageCard (as well as ImageCardList), and its namespace as you are using CoreVocabulary

Comment: In DXA 1.6, you may have to resort to debugging to understand why the mapping is failing. The model mapping logic is in `DefaultModelBuilder.CreateViewModel`: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/release/1.6/Sdl.Web.Tridion/Mapping/DefaultModelBuilder.cs